# How to use a template for all jQuery Mobile pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Behold: a footer template:

```
<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="templateFooter">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

In every mobile page I have:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">footer</div>
```

The way I'm currently loading the template is:

```
$(function() {
    $('div[data-role=footer]').html($('#templateFooter').html());
    $.mobile.activePage.trigger('create');
});
```

This works, but I don't really like using $(function(), but I need to load it if *any* page shows, so pageinit or pageshow does not help. I'll be using knockout.js going forward, if that is of any help.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getTemplateFooter() {
    //return footer text here
}


$("div:jqmData(role='page')").live("pagebeforecreate",function() {
    // get the footer of the page        
    // if footer doesn't exist on page, insert it where you want it... in this case after role="content"?
    var $content =$(this).page().find('div:jqmData(role="content")');
    $content.after(getTemplateFooter());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for: once-off run per page. To quote docs: _Note that by binding to pagebeforecreate, you can manipulate markup before jQuery Mobile's default widgets are auto-initialized. For example, say you want to add data-attributes via JavaScript instead of in the HTML source, this is the event you'd use._

Answer (score 0):

there is also a pageshow event, that one fires even if the user navigates to the page, through a back button press etc... it bubbles up to the page div

I use it for pages where lots of dynamic data could change between subsequent visits, or even when the user just presses back